# If $p$ is an odd prime with primitive root $1<r<p$, is $r$ also a primitive root modulo $p^2$?

Tags: primitive-roots

I use excel computed till $p=23$, it's true. But is this *always* true? if not, could you pls give a counter example?

Comment: That's not very far.

Comment: It may happen that $r^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$, I suppose

Comment: @AnginaSeng thanks for the hint, yeah I just need to go one step further :p

Comment: Try ```Table[SubsetQ[PrimitiveRootList[Prime[n]^2], PrimitiveRootList[Prime[n]]], {n, 1,100}]``` on Mathematica.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1599492/589 and https://oeis.org/A060503

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to dot it that $r=14$ is a primitive root for $p=29$, but not for $p^2=841$. Instead $r+p = 43$ is a primitive root for $841$.